# Is there a static value defined in the .NET framework for sql server's date range?

Tags: .net, sql-server

Is there a static value defined in the .net framework library similar to DateTime.MinValue and DateTime.MaxValue except with values that reflect Sql Server's datetime datatype range? (January 1, 1753 - December 31, 9999)

Comment: What's your intended use?  Assuming you're using CLR, you could define them as constants in the assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SqlDateTime.MinValue
SqlDateTime.MaxValue

Comment: FYI, they are contained in the System.Data.SqlTypes namespace